# Automatic Validation of Foreign Key not working Core 2.1

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core

I'm trying to set up an API in .Net-Core 2.1. I've been following this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and ran into the issue with the model not automatically validating as it should (according to [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#automatic-http-400-responses)). Specifically, I want to make sure that if a POST request is sent with a ForeignKey that does not exist I should get BadRequest response. If a correct ForeignKey is sent the request is correctly processed.

**Action**:
Sending a POST request to add a Campaign with a CustomerId that does not exist.

**Expected**:
Receive a BadRequest response

**Actual**:
The API crashes due to an unhandled DbUpdateException.

My files looks as follows:

**Context.cs**

```
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
         public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options)
       : base(options)
        { }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    }
```

**Campaign.cs**

```
    public class Campaign
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long CustomerId { get; set; }
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

    }
```

**Customer.cs**

```
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CampaignController.cs**

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CampaignController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly Context _context;

        public CampaignController(Context context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //Get Methods

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create(Campaign campaign)
        {
            _context.Campaigns.Add(campaign);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer", new { id = campaign.Id }, campaign);
        }

    }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
        services.AddDbContext<Context>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supposed to work that way. The controller won't validate your DB foreign keys. The validation is here to validate your ViewModel constraints, like `[Required]`, ...

Documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1